# Jquery: How to get parent div of an element and clone it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On the click of addField_1 button, I have to clone the container div(id = 'projection') and append it right below it.

I am doing this in `jquery` like this:

```js
$('[id^="addField"]').click(() => {
    var containerDiv = $(this).parent();
    console.log(containerDiv.attr('id'));
    containerDiv.after(containerDiv.clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="projection" >
    <select class="form-control" aria-placeholder="Select field"></select>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="addField_1" name="mybutton">+</button>
</div>
```

There is no error when the button is clicked. But the div is not being copied. I also tried to log the parent div's id. It is also undefined. Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: `addField` is `addField_1` ?

Comment: There is no error when i try and it works on the first click, but note all click events on the cloned content will not work due the new elements don't have the click event bound. So you could try with `$('.row').on('click','[id^="addField"]',() => {})`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini `$('[id^="addField"]')` means "select any element that has 'id' attribute starts with 'addField'

Comment: No, it's 'starting with addField'. I have used the carat sign for that.

Comment: you need to use `classes` instead of `id`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra the click event is triggered by all `id` starting with `addField`. Hes code is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you have used arrow function because of which `this` is referring to the `window`.

There are two solutions for it :

**1. Using `event.target` in the arrow function to get the targeted element.**

```js
$('[id^="addField"]').click((event) => {
    let containerDiv = $(event.target).parent();
    console.log(containerDiv.attr('id'));
    containerDiv.after(containerDiv.clone()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="projection" >
    <select class="form-control" aria-placeholder="Select field"></select>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="addField_1" name="mybutton">+</button>
</div>
```

---

**2. To not use arrow function but anonymous function and use `this` :**

```js
$('[id^="addField"]').click(function() {
    let containerDiv = $(this).parent();
    console.log(containerDiv.attr('id'));
    containerDiv.after(containerDiv.clone()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="projection" >
    <select class="form-control" aria-placeholder="Select field"></select>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="addField_1" name="mybutton">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With this keyword, you will reference to Window object.

That why you should use something like that:

```
$('[id^="addField"]').on('click', event =>  {
  const parentDiv = $(event.target).closest('.row');
  console.log(parentDiv.html());
});
```